# Watching attributes in a custom directive - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Brief background: I'm trying to write a directive that will listen to my bootstrap dropdown menu's aria-expanded attribute, because I want to do something once its value becomes false. From what I understand, this is the "angularJS" way if you want to monitor class changes inside elements.

The aria-expanded class is in this img element. My directive's name is **overlay-monitor**:

```
<img ng-init="displayMainMenu()" overlay-monitor id="nav-burger" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="sMainMenu=true; isSubMenu=resetMenu(); getLinks(); bStopPropagation=true;" src="img/burger.png">
```

What I really want it to do is to close the opaque overlay I have on the page if aria-expanded becomes false. But for now, I'm just trying to trigger an alert to see if I did it right:

```
app.directive('overlayMonitor', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { ariaExpanded: '@' },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        if (element.attrs('aria-expanded') == "true") {
            alert('directive');
        }
    }
}

});
```

When I tested it out, the alert didn't show. :(

What did I do wrong?

Please advise. Thank you!

**P.S.** I forgot to mention. We are not allowed to use jQuery. Thanks again for your replies!

---

**Edit:** After reading about $watch, I tried the following code:

```
app.directive('overlayMonitor', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { ariaExpanded: '@' },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            if (!attrs.ariaExpanded) {
                alert('false');
            }
            else {
                alert('true');
            }
        });
    }
}

});
```

Good news is that the alert popped up. Bad news is the alert only said "false". It never fired alert('true'). :/

Comment: I can't see you using aria-expanded="true".

Comment: I also don't think you're triggering diggest cycles when closing the menu.

Comment: Does `aria-expanded` get set to the string `"false"` or boolean `false`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this:

```
if (attrs.ariaExpanded) { // instead of element.attrs('..')
   alert('directive');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhojendra! However the alert fired only after initial page load. It no longer fired afterwards. How do I make it so that the alert will pop up everytime aria-expanded becomes false?

Comment: when aria-expanded becomes false?

Comment: It becomes false when the bootstrap dropdown menu is collapsed.

Comment: So, you need to trigger the function in the onchange event.

Comment: Yep, I changed it to that, that's why the alert went off. :) But only after page load, not everytime I collapse the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

The function `link` is executed once, when the rendering directives.

Therefore, to track changes in a variable you need to use a `$watch`.

Try following:

```
app.directive('overlayMonitor', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: { ariaExpanded: '@' },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(function(){ return attrs.ariaExpanded; },
    function(val){
      if (!val) {
         alert('directive');
      }
    });
 }
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stepan! I tried your solution, however the alert fired only after page load. It didn't fire whenever I collapse the menu. :(

Comment: Ok. We need example of your code in jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: We need to see what value takes `attrs.ariaExpanded`. For example `true` or `"true"`.